# Adding Nested form rows PHP/Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

**Overview:**
I am creating a dynamic web invoicing system,
Most of the page are textareas and I have used tables to nest as they will post data into seperate tables after the form is submitted. When the "Nested" Add a Row is selected, it should add a row inside with form field that has details on which row and which position so it can be gathered in a for loop when it is posted.

Image:
[image]

**Problem:**

1. Adding a row in the circled area does not add it in the last row, It add's it as it is in the image. Additionally it only works on the first item, the second add a row does not even register a click.
2. I am unsure how to get the variables to create the form name[][] in this particular index size and the parents index number (located in javascript line 2-3)

**Relevent Code:**

Javascript

```
$("#additemrow").click(function(){
  var currentListItem = $(this).length;
  var currentJobItem = $(this).parents('#items').index('#items');
  currentListItem++;
  $("#listitem:last").after(/*Blank Form Row*/);
  bind();
})
```

PHP

```
<table id="items">
  <tr class="item-row"><td>/*form elements*/</td></tr>
  <tr class="list-row">
   <td colspan=5>
    <table class="itemlist">
     <?php
     $itemCount = 0;
     foreach($jobListItem as $items) {
      foreach($items as $item) {
       if($problem['item_id'] == $item['item_id']) { 
    ?>
    <tr id="listitem">
     <td class="list-item">
       <div class="delete-wpr">
         <textarea class="item" name="item[/*A PARENT ITEM NUMBER*/][<?php echo $itemCount;?>][item]"></textarea>
         <a class="deleteitem" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a>
        </div>
       </td>
      </tr>
     <?php
      }
      $itemCount++;
     }
    }
     ?>
     <tr>
     <td colspan="5"><a id="additemrow" href="javascript:;" title="Add a row">Add a row</a></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    //NEXT ITEMLIST GOES HERE
   </table>
```

EDIT: Foreach Loop is just used to get variables from a array.

Please let me know if you need more details or bits of code as im not sure if I have given enough information.

Comment: `currentListItem` is used to print the the index number of the nested form (rows containing part + quantity). `currentJobItem` is used to print the index of the parent of the item (rows containing the price and labour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the problem where your row gets insertet at the top:

- Like Bertrand Lefort already said: in JQuery you can append nodes to the **end** of another (parent) node by calling `parent_node.append(child_node)` (more information [here](http://api.jquery.com/append/))
- You can also add elements before/after another element by calling [`another_element.before(element)`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) / [`another_element.after(element)`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) or (be aware of reversed syntax!) [`element.insertBefore(another_element)`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) / [`element.insertAfter(another_element)`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/)

Regarding the problem where only the first "add a row" registers a click:

- You're selecting by `id`. Id's are (or should be) unique, so when you call `$("#additemrow").click(function(){ ... })` the onClick-function will only be attached to the first element that matches the given id (as far as I remember).
- If you want to attach the same onClick-function to multiple elements use `class` instead. However, if you do so, you got to make sure you insert the new element *relative* to the clicked element (eg. by using `.parent()`, `.siblings()` or similar functions).

Regarding your problem #2, I don't really know what you're trying to do, but this is what I noticed:

- `currentListItem` and `currentJobItem` seem to be unused in their scope, since you are declaring them as local variables but not using them
- `.parents('#items').index('#items')` is redundant because `.parents('#items')` already selects only the parent elements that match `'#items'`. If you want to get the index of the matched element, use `index()` (without parameters, [see jquery API for more](http://api.jquery.com/index/))

Some other notes:

- If you have the time (and the need of a clean project) I recommend using template engines like Smarty to separate your logic from the output. This improves the readability of your code and also makes it easier to find/eliminate bugs.

I hope this helped a little bit. If you provide more information on what you're trying to do and what doesn't work as you expext, I will try to provide further help and update my answer.

Comment: I've had a rough week and didn't have the time to take care of this until now. I just noticed that your site changed significantly. Please let me know if you solved your problem. Cheers

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but that was the issue. I was referencing "id" not classes. Once I changed to classes they worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could add an id to the parent html element, then in your click handler:

```
$("#additemrow").click(function(){
   $("#parent").append(/*Blank Form Row*/);

})
```